# log4j is logging in the console but not creating a log file

Tags: java, log4j

I am using log4j in my project. The project is working fine but it is not creating a log file.

Here is the log4j.xml

```
<Configuration status="warn"> 
    <Properties> 
        <Property name="logHome">D:/logs</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders> 
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%-5p: %c - %m%n" />
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="rollingFile" immediateFlush="true" fileName="${logHome}/mySample.log" filePattern="${logHome}/mySample-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ} |[%t]| %-5p | %c{1} | %L - %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="5 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.springframework" level="info" includeLocation="true" />
        <Logger name="org.hibernate" level="info" includeLocation="true" />
        <Logger name="org.project" level="debug" includeLocation="true" />
        <Root level="info" includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="rollingFile" />
            <AppenderRef ref="console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if application have required permission to access the Drive. Try with D://log in logHome.
Also in which file you have added this configuration block.

Comment: @MayurJain I tried D://log still not working.

Comment: Also in which file you have added this configuration block.Have you checked if application have required permission to access the Drive?

Comment: @MayurJain the configuration block is in log.xml file. And I checked the application has permission to access the Drive.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the ways out but nothing worked for me. At the end I had to switch to slf4j.Logger and slf4j.LoggerFactory. With the help of this I was able to generate logs.
Example:

```
private static final Logger LOGGER=LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```